# Derivation of 2$\pi$ in the period of a simple pendulum

Tags: calculus, physics

Most of us know that the period of a simple pendulum is given by

$$2 \pi \sqrt{\dfrac{\ell}{g}}.$$

But how did the $2\pi$ term get into that argument. From dimensional analysis, we can find the period but not the constant.

Is there a calculus argument as some limit is taken? Is it based on an energy equation? Surely there is a way to derive that $2 \pi$.

Comment: Hint: The motion of a simple pendulum is a type of sinusoidal type motion.

Comment: Na that's an easy cop out. There must be a better argument.

Comment: Please stop voting to close, this is actually a good question.

Comment: @HansLundmark As evidenced by the range of different types of answers and by OP's comments to those answers, this question lacks way too many details to be properly answerable. I have no idea what OP actually is asking. For example, at first it just sounds like a question of how to derive the period of a pendulum, but apparently OP is also confused about how $2\pi$ comes into the period of $\sin(\omega t)$ – and one answer doesn't discuss the derivation at all but OP seems to be quite happy about it.

Comment: @JIK The question specifically asks about the $2\pi$ term. Nowhere is there a request for the solution of the differential equation that describes the simple pendulum.

Comment: @JiK: Fair enough, it was a bit of a stretch to call it a good question. But it's at least a question with a somewhat interesting *answer* (in my opinion), namely that it *is* possible to derive the period just from the expression for the conserved energy, without ever writing down the solution $\theta(t)$ explicitly (and this applies more generally too, not just for the linearized pendulum equation).

Comment: @JohnDouma _"Is there a calculus argument as some limit is taken? Is it based on an energy equation?"_ doesn't sound like OP knows everything else but has just forgotten how to get the period from the argument of a trigonometric function.

Comment: @JiK The answer to all of those questions is no. This is simple wave mechanics. The $2\pi$ comes from the fact that there are $2\pi$ radians per cycle.

Comment: @JohnDouma And where does the fact that $\alpha=1$ in the angular frequency $\alpha \sqrt{g/l}$ come from? Nothing in this question even hints that OP knows that it is $1$, only that they can do dimensional analysis to see that it's proportional to $\sqrt{g/l}$.

Comment: @JIK The solution for a harmonic oscillator is $A\cos(\omega t)$. In general it has a phase angle but we can ignore that because we can assume the oscillator starts in the displaced position. For the pendulum $\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}$ is the omega as you can verify by some of the submitted solutions.  This has units of $s^{-1}$ which we call radians per second. What units do you think its reciprocal has? The period is seconds per $2\pi$ radians which is not the same as seconds per radian.

Comment: @JohnDouma I don't understand the point of your comment. What in the question makes you think OP knows all that?

Comment: @JohnDouma Or specifically, that $\sqrt{g/l}$ is the omega.

Comment: His first statement says "Most of us know ...".

Comment: @JohnDouma Ok, now I'm absolutely completely totally lost on what you might possibly be thinking. The first statement already contains the answer. OP is asking *why* that is the answer. Surely you can't be using that same statement as the starting point on answering OP's question!?!??!?!

Comment: @HansLundmark _"But it's at least a question with a somewhat interesting answer (in my opinion),"_ That is true only if your interpretation of the question is correct. That was the problem I'm pointing out - there seems to be too many ways to interpret this question.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a simple question with a simple solution that has been over-complicated. Since the OP is not interested in accepting any answer it is probably best if he just takes high school physics where this is covered.

Comment: @Jik the issue is you can derive the period for a simple pendulum using dimensional analysis and Buckingham pi theorem and you don't need to know anything about the behavior of a simple pendulum to achieve this. However, you are left with an arbitrary constant. I'm wondering, if there is a way to derive the constant without just accepting that the motion is sinusoidal.

Comment: @HansLundmark I thought it was an interesting question. I'm lecturing dimensional analysis and I derived the period for the students. One student (who studies physics) asked how we can solve for the constant without knowing anything about the problem.  I told him that you need to look at the DE and the behavior of the pendulum to know its 2pi periodic. While this was a satisfying answer to the student im not happy with it. Dimensional analysis is powerful because you don't need insight into the problem, only the dimensions and variables. Similarly, can we find the constant in the same manner.

Comment: @KennyB: I think that if you had added that information to the question, it would have been received much more positively! [Context matters](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question#9960).

Comment: @HansLundmark will remember for future questions thanks Hans.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The pendulum movement equation is given by
\begin{align*}
\frac{\mathrm{d}^{2}\theta}{\mathrm{d}t^{2}} + \frac{g}{\ell}\sin(\theta) = 0
\end{align*}

For small values of $\theta$, we can make the approximation $\sin(\theta) \approx \theta$, from whence we obtain the equation
\begin{align*}
\ddot{\theta} + \frac{g}{\ell}\theta = 0
\end{align*}

whose associated characteristic equation is
\begin{align*}
x^{2} + \frac{g}{\ell} = 0 \Longrightarrow x = \pm i\sqrt{\frac{g}{\ell}}
\end{align*}

Thus the solutions are $\theta(t) = c_{1}\sin\left(\displaystyle t\sqrt{\frac{g}{\ell}}\right) + c_{2}\cos\left(\displaystyle t\sqrt{\frac{g}{\ell}}\right)$. Finally, for $T = 2\pi\sqrt{\displaystyle\frac{\ell}{g}}$, one has
\begin{align*}
\theta\left(t + 2\pi\sqrt{\frac{\ell}{g}}\right) = c_{1}\sin\left(t\sqrt{\frac{g}{\ell}} + 2\pi\right) + c_{2}\cos\left(t\sqrt{\frac{g}{\ell}} + 2\pi\right) = \theta(t)
\end{align*}
Therefore we conclude that $T$ is the period indeed.

Comment: I prefer this reasoning to the others presented. However, it's more like a good guess to make that substitution. I was hoping there might be a derivation of sorts. Maybe such a derivation doesn't exist?

Comment: @KennyB This is a standard method for solving a differential equation. No guessing is involved.

Comment: No no, what I mean is, the reasoning to substitute that form of T. It's not explicit if you don't know the behavior of the pendulum.

Comment: @KennyB it's explicit if you know that both sine and cosine have a periodicity of $2\pi$ and then look for time displacements that give you a displacement of $2\pi$. I have a simple demonstration for this but it is too big for this comment.

Answer (score 2):

The conserved energy is
$$
E = \tfrac12 m l^2 \dot \theta^2 + \tfrac12 mgl \theta^2
$$
so that the system moves on ellipses in the $(\theta,\dot\theta)$ plane.

The period is the time required to go once around an ellipse, which is twice the time it takes to go half a lap, say between $(\theta,\dot\theta)=(-\theta_0,0)$ and $(\theta_0,0)$ with $\dot\theta>0$, where $\theta_0$ is the amplitude of the oscillation, determined by the equation $E=0+ \tfrac12 mgl \theta_0^2$, that is,
$$
\theta_0 = \sqrt{\frac{2E}{mgl}}
.
$$
This gives
$$
T = 2 \int_{0}^{T/2} dt = 2 \int_{-\theta_0}^{\theta_0} \frac{d\theta}{d\theta/dt}
= 2 \int_{-\theta_0}^{\theta_0} \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{\frac{E- \tfrac12 mgl \theta^2}{\tfrac12 ml^2}}}
= 2 \int_{-\theta_0}^{\theta_0} \frac{d\theta}{\sqrt{\tfrac{g}{l}} \sqrt{\theta_0^2 - \theta^2}}
.
$$
Now let $\theta = \theta_0 \sin u$ to get
$$
T = 2 \sqrt{\tfrac{l}{g}} \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} \frac{1}{\sqrt{\theta_0^2 (1-\sin^2 u)}} \, \theta_0 \cos u \, du
= 2 \sqrt{\tfrac{l}{g}} \int_{-\pi/2}^{\pi/2} du
= 2 \sqrt{\tfrac{l}{g}} \cdot \pi
,
$$
as desired.

You can do the same thing for the full pendulum equation, without the small-angle approximation $\sin \theta \approx \theta$, where the energy is
$$
E = \tfrac12 m l^2 \dot \theta^2 - mgl \cos\theta
,
$$
but then you get a non-elementary integral (a so-called *complete elliptic integral*) which depends on the amplitude $\theta_0$ (or, equivalently, on the energy $E$), so that the period is some amplitude-dependent constant (greater than $2\pi$) times $\sqrt{\tfrac{l}{g}}$.

Comment: thanks for this answer. I think it's too advanced for the students I'm lecturing, but it's definitely useful and gives some insight into the problem. This also answers my question in the way that the 2pi term is only for the simple pendulum. This is perhaps why dimensional analysis just gives you a constant because it's independent of the small angle approximation.

Answer (score 0):

The Lagrangian of a simple pendulum is
$$L=\frac{1}{2}ml^2\dot{\varphi}^2+mgl\cos(\varphi)$$
Using harmonic approximation:
$$L=\frac{1}{2} ml^2 \dot{\varphi}^2+mgl\left(1-\frac{\varphi^2}{2}\right)$$
Leaving the constant out:
$$L=\frac{1}{2}ml^2 \dot{\varphi}^2-\frac{1}{2}mgl\varphi^2$$
Which will have the following equation of motion:
$$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \varphi}-\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}\varphi} \frac{\partial L}{\partial \dot{\varphi}}=0$$
I.e.
$$-mgl\varphi +ml^2 \ddot{\varphi}=0$$
$$\ddot{\varphi}=\frac{g}{l}\varphi$$
Which is a simple harmonic oscillator, with frequency $\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}$, so the period time will be $2\pi \sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}$.

Comment: Unfortunately, you're using the fact that the period is 2pi/omega where omega is the angular frequency. So you have really derived the 2pi

Comment: @KennyB The fact that the period is $2\pi/\omega$ comes from the fact that the solution is the linear combination of $\sin(\omega t)$ and $\cos(\omega t)$, and from the basic properties of the trigonometric functions.

Answer (score -2):

The expression $\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}$ represents the frequency in radians per second. Divide by $2\pi$ radians per cycle to get $\frac{1}{2\pi}\sqrt{\frac{g}{l}}$ cycles per second.

Now take the reciprocal to get $2\pi\sqrt{\frac{l}{g}}$ seconds per cycle which, by definition, is the period.

Comment: This is also one of the better reasonings for the 2pi term as compared to some of the other answers.

Comment: Why is it radians/sec and not cycles/sec? Both radians and cycles has dimension $1$, so I can't really see the reason.

Comment: @Botond What are the units of $\omega$ in $\cos{\omega t}$? Cycles are not unit-less but radians are.

Comment: The dimension of $\omega$ is $T^{-1}$. The same goes for cycles/sec, in my opinion.

Comment: @Botond Your opinion?

Comment: Yes, since I've not seen every physics book :)

Comment: The variable $\omega$ has units of radians per second. Therefore, its reciprocal is seconds per radian. The period is defined as seconds per $2\pi$ radians.

Comment: Since the premise of the question is that OP knows $\sqrt{g/l}$ only from dimensional analysis, the beginning of this answer makes it sound like dimensional analysis always gives the angular frequency.

Comment: That, I believe, is also what @Botond is asking about.

Comment: @JohnDouma In what sense are cycles not unitless? What is the unit?

Comment: They don't have units but they are not the same as radians. A cycle is $2\pi$ radians for this problem and in general is the length of the period.